# how can I avoid white spaces in oracle query result?

Tags: oracle

I am spooling data from oracle to write it in csv file.. Its fetching blank spaces with result. Is there any way to avoid those blank spaces??

Comment: Please accept answers to some of your previous questions and you will get more help in the future.

Comment: Sure.. I tried your suggestion ...

Comment: Hey thanks!! I was not aware of those things.. I was just increased the points :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [TRIMSPOOL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm#sthref968)

```
set trimspool on
```

Comment: +1 Been a while since I had to do this. `TRIMSPOOL` is definitely the way to go but I couldn't find the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RTRIM(columnname) AS columnname...
```

Comment: @Dinesh try `RTRIM()` instead

Comment: how can I write it in to the file??